Lock implementation via futex
I read ostep book. I stopped at the chapter about thread locks. There is implementation of mutex via futex:
void mutex_lock(int *mutex)
{
    int v;
    if (atomic_bit_test_set(mutex, 31) == 0)
        return;
    atomic_increment(mutex);
    while(1)
    {
        if (atomic_bit_test_set(mutex, 31) == 0)
        {
            atomic_decrement(mutex);
            return;
        }
        v = *mutex; 
        if (v >= 0)
            continue;
        futex_wait(mutex, v);
    }
}

void mutex_unlock(int *mutex)
{
    if (atomic_add_zero(mutex, 0x80000000)) // (1)
        return;
    // <-- (here)
    futex_wake(mutex); // (2)
}

I didn't understand why we need these three lines:
v = *mutex;
if (v >= 0)
    continue;

Let's consider all possibilities. When can it be? If some thread (first) acquired the lock and want to release it, another thread (second) is in while loop, if it is so => (1) case cannot be, because out of loop we increment mutex, it is mean that we are in (here) and *mutex is >= 0 now => scheduler interrupts
first thread in (here) and switches to second thread, I think that only in this case we need these lines (I have no ideas of other possibilities), but why we cannot remove them? If we remove them second thread go to sleep, e.g. futex queue and when scheduler switches to first thread he wake second thread up (2).

The implementation looks racy to me. And, it uses non-standard functions (that we have to guess at their exact functionality). What is atomic_add_zero? And, how does it clear the MSB (vs. atomic_bit_clear(mutex,31))? My guess on atomic_add_zero is that it returns true if the result is zero? I think I'd get a better book. I've rolled my own mutexes using atomics and futex* and (without thinking too much), my spidey sense is tingling :-)

"I didn't understand why we need these three lines:"  these lines mean that we are not interested in mutex values that are greater than or equal to zero;  that we won't be handing such values to futex_wait() -- only negative mutex values will be given to futex_wait().
